# Захват типа для mapStateToProps

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

прикручиваю typescript к react

вот так приблизительно выглядят мои компоненты:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { storeState } from '../../store/store';
import { ThunkDispatch } from 'redux-thunk';
import { AnyAction } from 'redux';

type ControlsProps = {
  tags: Array<string>;
  isLoading: boolean;
  limit: number;
  dispatch: ThunkDispatch<storeState, {}, AnyAction>;
}


class Controls extends Component<ControlsProps, {}> {
...
}

export default connect(
  (store: storeState) => ({
    isLoading: store.loading,
    limit: store.filters.limit,
    tags: store.tags,
  }),
)(Controls);
```

получается дублирование перечисления пропсов.

при этом, если я поменяю сигнатуру редьюсера, то в mapStateToProps у меня изменения сразу подтянутся через экспортированный тип, а вот в ControlsProps нужно не забыть внести изменения руками, да еще и опечатку можно допустить и никто не ругнется.
а хотелось бы все прописать 1 раз в mapStateToProps и чтобы изменения сами подхватывались в ControlsProps.

есть ли способ захватить тип возвращаемого mapStateToProps значения?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { storeState } from '../../store/store';
import { ThunkDispatch } from 'redux-thunk';
import { AnyAction } from 'redux';

const mapStateToProps = (store: storeState) => ({
  isLoading: store.loading,
  limit: store.filters.limit,
  tags: store.tags,
});

type StateProps = ReturnType<typeof mapSateToProps>;

type ControlsProps = {
  dispatch: ThunkDispatch<storeState, {}, AnyAction>;
} & StateProps;

class Controls extends Component<ControlsProps, {}> {
...
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Controls);
```